# Audio merge using FFMPEG Android

Tags: java, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I am trying to merge two audio files using ffmpeg with below command:

```
String files = "-i " + voiceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -i " + beatFile.getAbsolutePath();
String filter = " -filter_complex [0:a]volume=0.99[a1];[1:a]volume=0.3[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,volume=1.3,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[out]";
String output = " -map [out] -strict -2 \"" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

But Im getting error

> "/sdcard/merged_audio.mp3: No such file or directory"

---

Java code is

```
public void mergeAudio(File voiceFile, File beatFile) {

    File outputFile = new File(getMusicFilename());
    try {
        outputFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String files = "-i " + voiceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -i " + beatFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String filter = " -filter_complex [0:a]volume=0.99[a1];[1:a]volume=0.3[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2,volume=1.3,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[out]";
    String output = " -map [out] -strict -2 \"" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String cmd = files + filter + output;
    String[] command = cmd.split(" ");
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getActivity());
    try {

        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.v("onProgress", message);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.v("onFailure", message);
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.v("onSuccess", message);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v("finsish", "finish");

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
}

private String getMusicFilename() {
    fileUrl ="/sdcard/" + File.separator
            + "merged_audio.mp3";
    return fileUrl;
}
```

Comment: The error message is fairly self explanatory. Does the file exist?

Comment: file is existing in the given path

Comment: I hate to argue, but your error message says otherwise. are you sure your code is actually pointing to that directory?

Comment: yeah Im checking the file exist.

Comment: thats not what i asked. Im asking if your code is actually pointing to that file. Check your filepath, because the `No such file or directory` error wouldnt appear if the file was where it was looking.

Comment: Im getting tired of repeating myself. The error is saying its not where you are pointing. This means **it is not there** Post your code so we can see whats actually happening.

Comment: Check you have write permission to create the output file. Doesn't seem related to the inputs

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are given

Comment: Save it on internal storage and try.

Comment: tired internal storage giving same error

Comment: Hii, Have you get solution on this ? If you find any solution please share.. please..

Comment: DID you fixed this issue?

Comment: Call ffmpeg.loadBinary(new FFmpegLoadBinaryResponseHandler() {